# how to format backslash in JSON - iOS

Tags: ios, .net, nsdate, restkit

I am using RestKit to call a service , which is a .NET web service, the date formate required as one of the parameter is `"\/date(3467348+0000)\/"` so I am formatting date in the required format and sending , issue is when i check log the HTTP request shows the date as `"\\\/date(3467348+0000)\\\/"` , I am not sure if RestKit adding these additional backslashes , question is how to avoid it.
Date is formatted as follows

```
NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\/Date(%@+%2.1f)\\/",strSeconds,timeZoneOffset];
```

and the request shows date as

```
 PickupDateTime":"\\\/Date(1422880979912+5.5)\\\/"
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to escape slashes in the string, the format should be `"/date(3467348+0000)/"`.

The backslashes is in the format string. I think that you can just remove them:

```
NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%@+%2.1f)/",strSeconds,timeZoneOffset];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%@+%2.1f)/",strSeconds,timeZoneOffset];
```

removing both '\' should fix it